# rake assets:precompile aborted due to seemingly ok database.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I tried to precompile assets, and I got an error, which i looked up and it said to change my database.yml file. Fine. Now I'm getting this:

```
$ bin/rake assets:clean
rake aborted!
(<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 9 column 1
-- etc --
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password:

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/username_dev

test: &test
  <<: *default
  database: db/username_test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer when I pasted the code into the question. The issue was that there were tab indentations, which broke it.

Moral of the story: Use soft tabs (2 spaces) for the `database.yml` file.

Comment: Had the same issue a while ago, also because of yml two-space requirement. Not a big fan.